# Why would you subtract two acceleration vectors in the same direction?

Tags: vectors

So I was reading a book and came across a section where they were discussing the effect of earth's rotation on your effective weight.

It reads as follows:

> In this example, the angular velocity is approximately a constant
> which is the angular displacement divided by the elapsed time The
> person travels in a full circle (2π radians) in 23 hours and 56
> minutes which is 8.616e4 seconds. (Earth is orbiting the sun so it
> takes earth an extra four minutes of spinning to bring the sun to the
> same point in the sky, which is why the day is 24 hours).
>
> I can now calculate Tabitha's effective weight by the following
> equation *(not sure how to do latex on this site, sorry)*:
> F_g,eff = m[g-a_r]

So here's my question

Why subtract a_r from g? Because both are pointing towards the center of the Earth right? So why would I subtract these vectors and not add them? Sure, they're both pointed in a negative direction, but then by my reckoning just do the following:
F_g,eff = m*-[g+a_r]
right? Why not do that? These two vectors are pointed in the same direction so why take the difference between them?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on how to do LaTeX/MathJaX on this site.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll implicitly work with forces and accelerations that only act in the vertical direction.

Newton's second law is
\begin{equation}
F_N + F_g = ma
\end{equation}
where $F_N$ is the normal force acting on Tabitha, $F_g=mg$ is the gravitational force on Tabitha, $m$ is Tabitha's mass, and $a$ is Tabitha's acceleration. The effective weight $W_{\rm eff}$ is the force that would be exerted on a scale if Tabitha was standing on one. This force is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the normal force, $W_{\rm eff}=-F_N$. Therefore
\begin{equation}
W_{\rm eff} = -F_N = F_g - ma = m(g-a)
\end{equation}
Physically, one way to understand the minus sign is that the effective weight is equal to the force in a non-inertial reference frame that is traveling with Tabitha, and in that frame there is a "fictitious force" $-ma$ that partially cancels the gravitational force $mg$.

Answer (score 1):

> Because both are pointing towards the center of the Earth right?

Wrong. As Tabitha is in a non-inertial reference frame moving with the earth's surface, the acceleration $a_r$ points opposite to $g$ as caused by the fictitious centrifugal force in the upward direction. As a result, Tabitha feels lighter.